# Building a C++ project using rake in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, rake, rakefile

I have a `C++` project that I build using `rake` rather than `make`. To set this up in Eclipse I disabled the CDT and Scanner builders and created a rake builder pointing to the rake executable. This causes the project to be built correctly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>. However, the C++ error parser doesn't seem to be kicking in on the output.

What do I need to do to get g++ output processed by the error parser?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

1. In the C/C++ Projects view, right-click the project, and select Properties.
2. Expand C/C++ Build.
3. Select Settings.
4. Click the Error Parsers tab.
5. In the Error parsers list, select error parsers.
6. Click OK.

Refer: [Adding a C++ Error Parser in Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_error_parser.htm)